# Flash AS3 Drawing a line between two objects with different parents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I have two objects with different parents and I want to draw a line between them, how do I do this? I know I need to use localToGlobal but I am not really sure how to make it work for this. Basically I need the x and y coordinates of both objects relative to one of them, how do I get the x and y coordinates of on object relative to another when they have different parents? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the code you've already tried? People will be more willing to help if you show that you've already made an effort.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually you basically need to do this (draw the dashes, but as a solid line)

```
parent
|      \
child1--child2
```

[some code (typed but not tested)]

```
var start:Point = parent.globalToLocal(child1.localToGlobal(new Point()));
var end:Point = parent.globalToLocal(child2.localToGlobal(new Point()));
parent.graphics.lineStyle(1);
parent.graphics.moveTo(child1.x,child1.y);
parent.graphics.lineTo(child2.x,child2.y);
```

[another option]

```
var start:Point = child1.getRect(parent).topLeft;
var end:Point = child2.getRect(parent).topLeft;
parent.graphics.lineStyle(1);
parent.graphics.moveTo(child1.x,child1.y);
parent.graphics.lineTo(child2.x,child2.y);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001308.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001320.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal()
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal()

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect()

Answer (score 0):

it's:

```
var object1Pos:Point = object1.localToGlobal(new Point());
var object2Pos:Point = object2.localToGlobal(new Point());
```

Now you have to draw the line

```
var line:Shape = new Shape();
var g:Graphics = line.graphics;
g.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
g.moveTo(object1Pos.x, object1Pos.y);
g.lineTo(object2Pos.x, object2Pos.y);
```

Then, of course, add the line to the stage

```
stage.addChild(line);
```

Comment: `line.graphics` instead of `line.shape.graphics`, otherwise yes.

Comment: ah, i wrote `.shape.graphics` because line was (incorrectly) a sprite. changed it to a shape and removed `.shape` thanks :)

Comment: Actually I use Sprites as both holders and shapes, and a Sprite definitely has a `graphics` property, even more, it gets displayed.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right! I always made a shape with its `.graphics` then added it to a Sprite. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute coordinates (really, its relative to the stage) of any child of a child of a child... and just draw between them, on the stage :) this way it matters not how deep the two children are.